# Good practice of using android activities

Tags: java, android, performance

I completed few android apps successfully but always I feel that I am not following the best practices of android developnment.

Few things which makes me feel developing a 100% complete android app is tough are
  1. Making sure that my app is following all memory management stuffs
  2.Making sure that my app is not going  to crash
  3.This one is always a big confusion for me-
    I put all my code in oncreate() method including event listeners, phonestate listeners(If I require)  etc..

What is the use of other methods like onResume(), onPause()...  (I understood the concept of    when they are called)

Should I stop all my event listeners in onPause() or by default android clears it?

Can I put all my event listener in onResume()?

Comment: This question is not quite good for SO, better try to ask here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best reference for activity lifecycle callbacks is probably the the Android developers guide, and in particular this part:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

> Should I stop all my event listeners in onPause() or by default android clears it?

Either there or in onDestroy() but it depends what you're using them for; if you want the listener to listen even while that activity is paused or stopped then obv. stopping in onDestroy() is better.

> Can I put all my event listener in onResume()?

It depends, onCreate() is only called once when your activity first starts up, whereas onResume() is called when your activity starts as well as every time your activity comes back from being paused or stopped. So if you stopped listening in onPause() then you probably want to start listening again in onResume(). If you stop listening in onDestroy() then you probably want to start listening in onCreate().

Answer (score 1):

[Check dev Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

when ever over activity come in on stack again like previous it was not delete from stack then on resume is calling like if u want to see any list from any web service then after light off and again screen light is on then onresume() is call and u can call that webservices here and arrange list view with update values.

when ever your application go in pause mode then onpause() will call

you can follow above link i think your all query regards this will solve

Comment: Thank you for answering but I know, when and how lifecycle of an android app called...  and this doesn't answer anything in my question.